# How do I get my line graph to add to the previous data point?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, linegraph

I'm trying to create a line graph that shows the total breweries in a city over a period of time. The graph isn't adding on to the previous data point, it's just starting over from each new date.

This is the data set I'm working with:

```
Year Opened City Brewery Name
2012    Charlottesville 1
Fredericksburg  1
Norfolk 1
2013    Leesburg    1
Manassas    2
Richmond    2
2014    Fredericksburg  1
Purcellville    3
Richmond    4
Roanoke 3
Virginia Beach  3
2015    Fredericksburg  2
Leesburg    1
Manassas    1
Norfolk 1
Richmond    1
Sterling    1
Virginia Beach  2
```

Here is the graph code:

```
# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
# use unstack()
top10brew_df.unstack().plot(kind='line', y="Brewery Name", ax=ax)
```

[what my graph looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vllx1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use reindex and fill values with 0

```
df = df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Opened City',values='Brewery Name').reindex(range(2012,2015)).fillna(0)
```

[image]

Plot the results

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
plt.xticks(df.index.values.astype(int))
df.plot.line(ax=ax)
```

[image]